# Password reset not redirecting to template html file in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a template html file for my password reset form. But it is not redirecting to my template file rather it is redirecting ti Django administration page. I don't want to use django administration page for resetting the password change link.

password_reset_form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'employeeregistration/css/master.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <div class="container title">
      <h2 style="text-align:center; padding-top:100px;">Reset your password</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <form  method="POST" action="{% url 'password_reset' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}

          {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send confirmation mail</button>
          {% endbuttons %}

      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'registration'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html"), name='login'),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_form.html"), name='password_reset'),
    # path('password_reset/password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="registration/password_reset_done.html"), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.EmployeeSignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),

]
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import(LoginRequiredMixin,
                                       PermissionRequiredMixin)
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                  DetailView,CreateView,
                                  UpdateView,DeleteView)
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms


class EmployeeSignUp(CreateView):
    """
    Views for employee sign up
    """
    form_class = forms.NewEmployeeRegistrationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'



class AdminView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/admin.html'
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# from django.contrib.auth import views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('registration/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('registration/', include('registration.urls', namespace='registration')),
    # path('registration/password_reset', include('registration.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
    # path('registration/password_reset_done', include('registration.urls', namespace='password_reset_done')),

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have specified a namespace, in the action attribute in password_reset_form.html, you have to first specify the name of the namespace the name of the view separated by a colon. You can find the appropriate documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs)
So you have to change password_reset_form.html to-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'employeeregistration/css/master.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <div class="container title">
      <h2 style="text-align:center; padding-top:100px;">Reset your password</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <form  method="POST" action="{% url 'registration:password_reset' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}

          {% buttons %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send confirmation mail</button>
          {% endbuttons %}

      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also you have two paths in your root project urls.py which lead to the same url. So consider changing it to

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
# from django.contrib.auth import views
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    # path('registration/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('registration/', include('registration.urls', namespace='registration')),
    # path('registration/password_reset', include('registration.urls', namespace='password_reset')),
    # path('registration/password_reset_done', include('registration.urls', namespace='password_reset_done')),

]
```

I have commented out one url pattern which might be causing the issue.

Comment: You have two paths in your root project urls.py which lead to the same url.

Comment: It is working. I had to change the name of my app. May be registration name is conflicting with django admin